# Ballsed up with ccsm, can't see unity any more

Tags: 14.04, ccsm

Im running ubuntu 14.04
Whilst playing with ccsm, which I know nothing about, I inadvertently ballsed up my desktop and. Ow I can't see the unity bar or launch anything.

I think its because I did something with the'Expo' setting then blithely ignoring a warning about Unity.

Anyone help me undo my mistake and get unity back?
That ks

Comment: If you can open ssh from terminal, then just turn on Unity plugin,

Answer (score 0):

Settings in CCSM are user-specific. This means you can delte them by deletiong some files in home folder, but I do not know what. 
What I can say is: As a last resort, get to console (Ctrl Alt F1) and create a new user (`adduser unitybreaker` or smth.). Then relogin as that user.

Comment: Ctrl alt T doesn't work, neither does Ctrl alt f1